# How to access base object from inside method Javascript

Tags: javascript

I've written a class and this is a snippet taken from it to demonstrate my problem.

```
<!--language:lang-js-->    
var myclass = function () {
    this.addItem = function () {
        //generateDiv and append..
        //generatedeletebtn and append
        btn.onclick = this.deleteItem; 
    }
    this.deleteItem = function () {
        console.log(this);
    }
}
```

Inside the `deleteItem` function, `this` represents the HTML element clicked. Is there a way I can access the myclass object directly?

I've tried changing 
`div.onclick = this.deleteItem` 
to
 `div.onclick = this.deleteItem(this)` which works as far as accessing the object but the parenthesis invoke the function and remove the items as soon as they're added so that's no good.

Comment: Do you need to access the myclass object and also the element that's been clicked (within the `deleteItem` function)? Or do you just need the myclass object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a job for [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

```
btn.onclick = this.deleteItem.bind(this);
```

You can think of `bind` as wrapping *function A* referenced by `this.deleteItem` in another *function B*, which always invokes *A* with the context given as the first parameter of `bind`.

There is a polyfill available on *MDN* if you can't assume `bind` is available in your environment.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the closure to store a reference to the `myclass` object itself in a variable called `that`. Then, when `deleteItem` is eventually called, it should use the `myclass` object as `that`.

```
var myclass = function () {
    var that = this;

    this.deleteItem = function () {
       console.log(that);
    }
}
```

You shouldn't have to worry about polyfills with this one.

Comment: +1 because this saves memory when new functions don't need to be created each time, but also remember that if you're creating many instances of `myclass`, they will not be destroyed until **all references** to that instance has been destroyed (i.e. everywhere `deleteItem` was assigned, true for my answer too).

Comment: Worked in theory but if I had 3 instances of myclass for some reason it was only targeting the last created instance whereas bind worked for each one uniquely.

Comment: @Kiee sounds like you were forgetting to `var` (or used `var` in the wrong place)